# Can't get C Program to Build

Tags: c, eclipse, compilation

I am trying to execute the c program found [here](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/testpi/nearpi.c).  But when I try to build it in eclipse I get numerous errors about functions being implicitly declared and registers being accessed that don't exist.  I was wondering if anybody can get this code to run and how they got it to work (program, OS, etc.)  I am on a windows machine using an ubuntu virtual machine with eclipse and gcc to try and execute this code.

Here is a list of errors from Eclipse SDK (I have fixed a few bugs from the original code):

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project nearpi ****

make all 
Building file: ../src/nearpi.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/nearpi.d" -MT"src/nearpi.d" -o "src/nearpi.o" "../src/nearpi.c"
../src/nearpi.c:465:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wreturn-type]
../src/nearpi.c: In function ‘main’:
../src/nearpi.c:501:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘input’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
../src/nearpi.c:532:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘nearPiOver2’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
../src/nearpi.c:540:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘dbleCF’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
../src/nearpi.c: At top level:
../src/nearpi.c:590:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wreturn-type]
../src/nearpi.c:694:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wreturn-type]
../src/nearpi.c:756:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wreturn-type]
../src/nearpi.c: In function ‘nearPiOver2’:
Finished building: ../src/nearpi.c
../src/nearpi.c:935:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

../src/nearpi.c: In function ‘input’:
../src/nearpi.c:748:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
Building target: nearpi
../src/nearpi.c: In function ‘main’:
Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc  -o "nearpi"  ./src/nearpi.o   -lm
../src/nearpi.c:564:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Finished building target: nearpi

Comment: If you could post the specific errors that would help.

Comment: You're missing a header file.

Comment: I think you need some more comments: but seriously, you need to post the exact errors and the way in which you called the compiler.

Comment: I am calling the compiler by pressing the hotkey combination CTRL+F5 in eclipse to build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That code has bugs in it, when compiled on a modern compiler[*]. If I were you, I'd contact whomever licensed it, and ask for my money back.

**Some** of the bugs are:

- Missing `#include <stdio.h>`, `#include <math.h>`
- It uses the `register` keyword inccorrectly. Delete that keyword everywhere it appears.
- It uses "%E" when it should have used "%lE".
- It uses "%08x" when it should have used "%08lx".
- It uses "1.0E" when it should have used "1.0".

If you fix all of those bugs, it runs. I don't know if it produces the correct answer, but it does run.

*<sup>That code was written in 1983, when the prevailing standard for C was the first edition of K&R. There have been three international standards for C published since then, and that code was never updated. Most of the bugs and warnings are a result of being very old.</sup>

Comment: I know what the correct answer is, I am not sure what the format of what it will print will look like, but I will know if it is correct when I see the output.

Comment: how do I fix the function declarations?

Answer (score 1):

You face only linking errors (in the current version of the question) like

```
undefined reference to `floor'
```

this indicates you need to add the math library by adding '-lm' to the compiler options.

Further explanations you find [here](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_17.html)

Comment: I knew about the -lm options, I just figured out how to properly do it in Eclipse so that it doesn't complain.